# How to shift a Bitmap and animate it

Tags: java, android

I want to move a Bitmap from an X,Y to a new X',Y' and animate it. I have an SurfaceView as an inner class of an Activity, and that SurfaceView is running as a thread and handling all the drawing on the canvas.

Here is the run method of the thread:

```
public void run() 
    {
        while(threadOk == true)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = null;
            try
            {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                letsDraw(canvas);
            }
            finally 
            {

                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the `letsDraw(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
public void letsDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 102, 0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(card.getPic(), card.getX(), card.getY(), null);
    }
```

The `card` is an instance of a custom class `Card(Bitmap pic, float X, float Y)`.
The thing is, I have know idea how to approach this situation. I want to "shift" the Bitmap a couple of pixels, and animate it while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong.

[Here](http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame2.html) is an example of what you should be doing.

Basically to "shift" (animate) the image you want to update the x and y coordinates and also redraw the view. This can be done by simply calling `invalidate()` at the end of your draw call.

Comment: I've been going through some tutorials on youtube, and the guy making them said this was the correct ways, as in the view runs as a separate thread. So you're saying I should not run it as a thread?

Comment: No, you have your draw calls in `letsDraw()` a method that is not needed. There are already pre-made methods available for you. In your case however if you don't want to change anything you can simply call `invalidate()` at the end of your draw call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can achieve this is calculating the X and Y position of the bitmap with an LinearInterpolator and drawing it on "letsDraw" method.